# Can't save an uploaded image using flask on python

Tags: python, image, flask, upload, save

I'm trying to deploy an age & gender model on local, using flask. Everything works fine but when I upload an image and make a predict, it doesn't save the image I've uploaded (but he makes the prediction, just doesn't show the image because it doesn't save to 'static/uploads' i defined

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/uploads/'

app = Flask(__name__)

# Define the upload folder
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route('/detect_age_gender', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def detect_age_gender():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        
        # Save the file to the 'static/uploads' folder
        file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(file.filename))
        file.save(file_path)

        # Use process function
        ar = process(file)

        # Predict age and gender using the provided models
        age = age_model.predict(ar)
        gender = np.round(gender_model.predict(ar))

        # Convert gender prediction to 'male' or 'female'
        if gender == 0:
            gender = 'Male'
        elif gender == 1:
            gender = 'Female'

        # Return result to the "result" page HTML
        return render_template('result.html', age=age, gender=gender, image_path=url_for('static', filename=f'uploads/{secure_filename(file.filename)}'))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Kinda new to flask. I can show the rest of my code if needed

Comment: Check the return value of: file.save

Comment: i tried to print but on my debugger i only see this : 

 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 744-149-307
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2024 22:14:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 220ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 196ms/step
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2024 22:14:49] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2024 22:14:49] "GET /static/uploads/8yo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: Did you create `static/uploads` directory?

Comment: Yes of course. That's why I don't get why he doesn't save my file into the folder. I'm stuck :/